# How do I generate an Azure SAS signature constraining Content-Length header to certain value?

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I am currently implementing ajax browser uploads straight to an azure storage container. First I need a signed url that will allow me to do that without sharing my private key with the browser (I ask my server for this signed URL on a previous ajax call).

My server side code looks like this;

```
public string GetSignature(string fileName, int contentLength)
{
    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = this.BlobClient.GetContainerReference("demo");

    CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("photo1.jpg");

    SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
    {
        Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Create,
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10)
    };

    SharedAccessBlobHeaders headers = new SharedAccessBlobHeaders()
    {
        CacheControl = "",
        ContentDisposition = "",
        ContentEncoding = "",
        ContentLanguage = "",
        ContentType = ""
        // PROBLEM: Where's content length?
    };

    return blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy, headers);            
}
```

My problem is that I can't find a way to specify the content length header. I need this to prevent users from uploading huge files once they have a storage quote that must be respected.

I have googled a lot and actually found a way to do this which is implementing the signature algorithm as per [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx), but implementing all of this myself is just my last resort (it will be more error prone and time consuming).

So my question is, is there a way to pass content length constraint to a `PUT` signed url?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way currently to put blob size limitations on delegated access. (The link you provided is for signing requests with the account key; it does not constrain the size of the blob being uploaded.)

There are two factors that limit the amount of data being uploaded in this scenario:

1. The time limitations of the SAS token. Your code shows a 10 minute window; assuming 60 MB/sec that allows for approximately 36 GB.
2. The maximum size of a single blob is a hard upper bound.

One solution is to scan the container periodically and clean up any blobs that go beyond the user's quota.

As a side point, the SharedAccessBlobHeaders control what the users see when they download the blob. They don't restrict what the user can upload, so they are not relevant to your scenario. You can simply pass in null for this parameter.